# Skype Desktop API and video recording

Tags: directshow, skype, skype4com

Skype Desktop API allows audio recording (both directions), but there are no options for video recording.

I can easily capture source video (from default capture device), but how can I capture incoming video?

There are some applications that do it by "screen capture" of skype video window (example is Pamela for Skype and results look ugly), but there are others which obviously have more sophisticated methods (example is **Evaer**). Any idea how Evaer achieves that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last time I checked Skype did not use DirectShow to present incoming video, they are using regular APIs (like GDI). This basically leaves you options to either read back from screen/DC, or hook the process and patch API function entries in order to intercept API calls to capture frames at the time they are painted (dirty stuff). I suppose the application you mentioned is using a similar trick. Perhaps they make things fancier by normalizing frame rate, removing artifacts, using high quality encoding etc. - all in all the output video might be looking decent.

Comment: I was afraid that this would be an answer. I'm just wondering why they don't expose it through API in a similar way they exposed audio. Btw. thank you for your blog, it is a life saver for every DirectShow developer.

Comment: I'd say video capabilities have not been a priority for Skype, and they were not investing effort into exposing video functionality on their API.