# Where can I find documentation on Skype Desktop API?

Tags: macos, api, skype

The Skype desktop API was being closed, but they've reversed that decision. I'm now not able to register as a developer (http://developer.skype.com/) as they're 'not accepting new registrations'.

I need to start looking into this as I want to develop a call recording component for Mac (and Windows, but most importantly Mac).

So is there a mirror for the documentation somewhere so that I know how this works? And is there any example code for this?

[A comment in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048861/skype-desktop-api-and-video-recording) seems to imply that they provide both tracks of audio readily so I believe that once I can get this info, it should be quite a simple task!

Comment: When I Googled "Skype API Documentation" I received dozens of useful links including massive PDFs. Do those not meet your needs until the official links come back?

Comment: I can't find anything relating for the Mac specifically though and I'm assuming things are at least a little different there? The closest I found really was [this one but I'm not sure](http://www.subdude-site.com/WebPages_Local/RefInfo/Computer/Linux/LinuxGuidesOfOthers/linuxProgrammingGuides/pdfs/PhoneAppProgramming/SkypeAPIguide_2005_62pgs.pdf) how useful that will be?

Comment: I read that 'The Skype API does not in itself expose the sound channel via the 
Skype API. However it does allow you to select what audio devices 
connect to the Skype Client. In this way you can route audio in and out of 
your Skype Client.' but this doesn't match up with something I read somewhere else which said they DO expose the audio. idk if this is still current as it's from 2005? Or maybe the other thing was incorrect?

Comment: can't the call recording component be built by using a audio routing mechanism? I wouldn't build something using Skype Desktop API at this point since they're most likely to disable it soon...

Comment: I would love to avoid using it but I don't know how I could route audio! Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out the Wayback Machine has my answer:

http://web.archive.org/web/20130607130426/http://dev.skype.com/desktop-api-reference

Who would have thought it? ;)

Comment: Marc how are you planning to use the obsolescent API? Through an old version of Skype?

Comment: It's not obsolete any more - they retracted and have kept the recording components of the API as there's no other way to do it.

Comment: What about the rest of the API, are you able to use them, like send a chat message? I had to install and older version of Skype to do that, as we need an internal chat bot here.

Comment: No, they've deprecated that functionality I think: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12349/skype-says-my-application-will-stop-working-with-skype-in-december-2013-why-is-that

Specifically 'some features of the API will stop working with Skype for desktop. For example, delivery of chat messages using the API will cease to work. However, we are happy to share that we will be extending support for two of the most widely used features – call recording and compatibility with hardware devices – until we determine alternative options or retire the current solution.'

Comment: I want a similar feature and went thru the documentation but it only gives voicemail recording. Is there a section for call recording that I am missing?

Comment: nm.. got it. Future REF: it is in "Voice Streams" section